# Why no overload chosen on forward reference for function templates?

Tags: c++, overloading, function-templates, forward-reference

Snippet:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct Printer{};

template<typename T>
void test(T&&)
{
    std::cout << "Primary template called\n";
}

template<typename T>
void test(Printer<T>&&)
{
    std::cout << "Specialized template called\n";
}

int main()
{
    auto t = Printer<int>{};
    test(0);
    test(t);
}
```

Here is the [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7Efv3G)

Why is two times `Primary template called` printed?

If one removes the forward reference from the second template, then the `Printer` overload is chosen.

Why is it not chosen with `&&`?

Comment: `&&` don't bind to lvalues, and `t` is an lvalue. `&&` is not a forwarding reference in your example, it is just an rvalue reference.

Comment: @Evg: Why does it bind to the first template then?

Comment: Because in `T&&`, `&&` is a forwarding reference, but in `Printer<T>&&`, `&&` is an rvalue reference. The only way to get a forwarding one is to write `T&&`. Even `const T&&` is no longer a forwarding reference.

Comment: Ok, I see...what is Printer<T&&> then?

Comment: `Printer` with `T` substituted with `T&&`. No magic's here. Only `T&&` are magical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forwarding reference only works for `T&&`, not `C<T>&&` nor `const T&&`.

```
test(0); // Call test(T&&) with T=int
test(t); // Call test(T&&) with T=Printer<int>&
```